# Execution time on VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

[image]

Hi, i want to show execution time for VScode more detail.

Here it shows metrics second such as 0.3s.

however, i wanna see it as milli-seconds (ms) or micro-seconds same as jupyter notebook as below.

[image]

Is there anyway to find this extention and install in VScode??